# nginx + php-fpm: how to specify memory limit for an application

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

With apache+php_mod it was as easy as putting:

```
php_value      memory_limit        128M
```

into application vhost.

How can I do something like this for nginx+php-fpm?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've got a couple of options. You can either:

1. Set the `fastcgi_param` of `PHP_VALUE` to be the relevant setting in the nginx configuration: `fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit = 128M";`
2. Set it via the `php_value` setting in the FPM pool configuration file. Something like `php_value[memory_limit] = 128M`. Use `php_admin_value` if you don't want the setting to be overridable via `ini_set`.

Comment: In the second case how to do that specifically for a given application/domain.

Comment: Run that application against a different PHP FPM pool.

Comment: doesnt work in nginx this way
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "fastcgi_param" directive in ...

Comment: Don't forget to restart nginx and php-fpm after you make these changes.

Comment: @growse, there is a missing semicolon at the end of fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit = 128M" else it gives an error. Thanks

Comment: I had to use `php_admin_value[memory_limit]` instead of `php_value[memory_limit]`. The difference between both, according to the documentation, is that the first cannot be overridden by `*.ini` files or `ini_set()`.